# maya calendar + icloud

Tags: release-loki, calendar

It's not possible at the moment to add iCloud calendars via CalDav. I know the url to use, based on https://www.nico-beuermann.de/blogg...ng_selected]=en&serendipity[user_language]=en

At least it should be possible to use the public published url, but that doesn't work: you're not allowed to add a calendar without authentication. If you just add a username, you'll get a http 500 error

Anyone know how to fix this ?

regards,
 Frederik

Answer (score 1):

It is actually possible to ad iCloud calendars via CalDAV. I'm doing it. Your issue might be that you have two factor authentication enabled for your icloud account. If that is the case, you need to generate an application password, here: https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage

Then, configuring maya is fairly straightforward:

[image: maya configuration]

But not everything is perfect. At least for me, there is a bug: The month view shows the appointments correctly, but the right panel (the day view) shows the appointments of the previous day.

Since this is somehow trying to use icloud calendars in an unsupported way, I have not bothered to report it.

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to configure the calendars using Evolution. Just install Evolution, add the calendars and afterwards you can remove Evolution again. Follow the steps as described here:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/911567/how-to-sync-icloud-calendar#911568

Look for the 2018 answer of @mniess. This worked like a charm for me. Calendars will automatically show up in elementary OS' default calendar app.